# c# winform travando quado a rede cai

Tags: c#, .net

tenho um sistema em windows form que necessita de uma verificação em loop o tempo todo. O problema que ta acontecendo é que quando a rede cai e este loop tenta conectar na base de dados a tela fica travada, e as vezes o usuário ate tem que fechar o sistema.

No meu Form_Load() eu instanciei um backgroundWorker
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E este é meu DoWork que ele executa
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a logica principal ocorre nesse **carregarDADOS()**, onde acessa varias vezes o banco de dados em seu ciclo. Dentro deste metodo, toda chamada a componentes do Treadh UI eu faço utilizando o BeginInvoke, sem invokar o form inteiro para evitar problema.

Nao sei se eu poderia estruturar de uma forma diferente isto e nem o ponto em que esta ocorrendo este gargalo quando a rede cai.

Comment: Lidar com desconexões envolve fazer um polling (consulta constante) no socket de rede, mas muitas vezes a API não expõe o socket. Existem várias questões sobre isso, a forma mais prática consiste em utilizar transactions e um bloco try/catch nas operações de rede, em caso de erro você recupera o estado anterior antes de tentar uma nova conexão.

Comment: cara isso que vc disse de recuperar o estado anterior antes de tentar uma nova conexão me deu uma ideia aqui que eu não tinha pensado. Se caiu uma vez no catch no momento de abrir a conexão, eu posso guardar esse estado e fazer com q este estado ative a verificação da rede, quando a rede voltar eu atualizo esse estado e desbloqueio a entrada para abrir a conexão nos metodos novamente.

Comment: +/- isso. O padrão é: Inicia-se uma conexão, prepara-se os comandos SQL e os dados a serem transimitods, inicia-se uma transação, faz-se todo trabalho em uma única conexão, por fim se tudo correr bem, confirma-se a transação com "COMMIT" no banco. O banco só sofrerá alterações se você chamar o commit da transação. No seu aplicativo cliente você coloca o bloco de interação com o banco dentro de um try/catch, se atente aos detalhes relativos ao tipo de erro que ocorrer para que possa tratar os diferentes erros. Caso tudo ocorra bem na interação com o banco você atualiza o cliente.

Comment: Se sua interação com o banco é muito demorada, você deve segmentar a interação e fazer por partes/chunks.